# Expected Value of Logit

Tags: probability-distributions, expected-value

If the only information that we know is that the following holds

$$\mathbb{E}[Y]=\frac{a}{a+b}$$

Is it possible for

$$\mathbb{E}[logit(Y)]=logit\Bigl(\frac{a}{a+b}\Bigr)$$

to hold?? Is there a property that might make it possible to hold?

Comment: what is $logit$? $\ln(p/(1-p))$?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Clearly, if $Y$ is constant, your property will hold, but if $Y$ is a general random variable, this is not true. So in general you seem to be asking under which conditions it is possible to interchange integration and a continuous function.

Comment: Yes that is true. But I found no such property, only Jensen which is for inequalities with convex functions.

Comment: @Jonathan1234 there isn't such a property to allow in general such a transformation